# Using a class method inside of a pyspark UDF

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Hello Data Engineers !

I am trying to write a pyspark udf using a method from a class called [Astral](https://github.com/sffjunkie/astral/blob/master/src/astral.py)

Here is the udf :

```
def time_from_solar_noon(d, y):
    noon = astral.Astral().solar_noon_utc
    time = noon(d, y)
    return time 

solarNoon = F.udf(lambda d, y: time_from_solar_noon(d,y), TimestampType())
```

Now the way I understand it, the class will be instantiated for **every single line** in my dataframe, resulting in a very slow job.

If I take the class instantiation out of my function :

```
noon = astral.Astral().solar_noon_utc

def time_from_solar_noon(d, y):
    time = noon(d, y)
    return time
```

I get the following Error message :

```
  [Previous line repeated 326 more times]
    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

So here is my question, I think it should be possible to have at least one class instantiation by executor/thread, instead of one by line in my dataframe, how would I do that ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: can you try `astral_ = astral.Astral(); solarNoon = F.udf(astral_.solar_noon_utc, TimestampType())`

Comment: Other classes can be instantiated in the way you mentioned. The line that is causing the `RecursionError` is `File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astral.py", line 1576, in __getattr__ for name, value in self._groups.items():`.

Comment: @cylim can you develop, this comes from the Geocoder class which I am not even using in this case (I already have lat/lon) data, I am going to make a fork with simplified functions

Comment: @Manu Valdés I have tried and got the same error

Comment: Have you considered using mapPartitions, rather than a UDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like with database connections, you can instantiate only a limited number of these class instances, by using `mapPartitions`:

```py
In [1]: from datetime import date
   ...: from astral import Astral
   ...: 
   ...: df = spark.createDataFrame(
   ...:     ((date(2019, 10, 4), 0),
   ...:      (date(2019, 10, 4), 19)),
   ...:     schema=("date", "longitude"))
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: def solar_noon(rows):
   ...:     a = Astral()  # initialize the class once per partition
   ...:     return ((a.solar_noon_utc(date=r.date, longitude=r.longitude), *r)
   ...:             for r in rows)  # reuses the same Astral instance for all rows in this partition
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: (df.rdd
   ...:  .mapPartitions(solar_noon)
   ...:  .toDF(schema=("solar_noon_utc", *df.columns))
   ...:  .show()
   ...:  )
   ...: 
   ...:  
+-------------------+----------+---------+                                      
|     solar_noon_utc|      date|longitude|
+-------------------+----------+---------+
|2019-10-04 13:48:58|2019-10-04|        0|
|2019-10-04 12:32:58|2019-10-04|       19|
+-------------------+----------+---------+
```

This is fairly efficient, as the function (`solar_noon`) is given to each worker and the class is only initialized once per partition, which can hold many rows.